# Нужна программа которая будит менять тип файла

Tags: java, python

Нужна именно программа , где будит только один функционал.
Если у файла тип .zip то поменять нужно на .mcpack
И на оборот , помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Программа-будильник?

Comment: нет , по сути программа замена текста. Я же уже объяснил что на что

Comment: да, если не сложно

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно максимально точно описывать ваш вопрос и приводить хотя бы примеры кода, потому-что для остальных пользователей это выглядит как **"Поищите там за меня и дайте решение, сам я не хочу тратить время и думать"**

Вам ставят минусы именно по этой причине, ну а пока я еще не научился читать мысли, попробую наугад дать вам подсказки.

**Насчет программ:**

[https://ezyzip.com/Конвертировать-zip-в-mcpack.html](https://ezyzip.com/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-zip-%D0%B2-mcpack.html)    это онлайн конвертер ZIP в .mcpack

https://pythonru.com/uroki/funkcija-zip-dlja-nachinajushhih  здесь вы можете найти информацию по Python по работе с ZIP файлами.

По крайней мере будет от чего оттолкнуться.